# BBP-Algorithm in Python - Working with Arbitrary-precision arithmetic

Tags: python, algorithm, pi, arbitrary-precision

I am writing on a term paper about the calculation of pi. While i have finished the theoretical site, i`m now struggeling implementing the BBP-Algorithm in Python.

You can find the BBP-Algorithm here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

And this is my Implementation in Python:

```
from sympy.mpmath import *
pi = mpf(0)
mp.dps = 30;
for n in range(0,500):
    pi = pi + mpf((1/16**n)*(4/(8*n+1)-  2/(8*n+4)-  1/(8*n+5)-  1/(8*n+6)) )


print(pi)
```

My Problem is, no matter how high i set k or how high i set the decimal places for pi i can`t get a higher precision than 16 digits.

I used mpmath for higher precision, because i encountered some problems before.

How can i improve my code, so i can get more digits ?

Comment: Looks to me that `16**500` simply cannot be represented by a `float` or `double` you convert to `mpf` too late.

Comment: @CommuSoft What do you mean by "you convert to mpf to late" ? What should i do ?

Comment: 16**500 can't be represented as `float`, by performing `mpf(16)**500` however, it can be represented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, python will use the standard floating points as defined by IEEE-754. This has a precision of some 12 digits and can represent numbers as lows as *2<sup>-1022</sup>*, now you can resolve this problem by calling the `mpf` operator earlier in the process, a more readable and more precise version is thus:

```
from sympy.mpmath import *
pi = mpf(0)
mp.dps = 30;
for n in range(0,500):
    u = 4.0/(8*n+1)-2.0/(8*n+4)-1.0/(8*n+5)-1.0/(8*n+6)
    u = mpf(u)
    d = mpf(16.0/1.0)**n
    pi += u/d

print(pi)
```

This however still has problems when you calculate the `u` part. To do it exactly, you can use:

```
from sympy.mpmath import *
pi = mpf(0)
mp.dps = 50;
for n in range(0,50000):
    u = mpf(4)/mpf(8*n+1)-mpf(2)/mpf(8*n+4)-mpf(1)/mpf(8*n+5)-mpf(1)/mpf(8*n+6)
    d = mpf(16.0)**n
    pi += u/d

print(pi)
```

Which is correct for the first 50 digits:

```
3.1415926535 8979323846 2643383279 502884197 1693993751
```

(spaces added)

Comment: First of all Thank You! Is there any more optimization possible, or is an calculation improvement only possible by raising the used decimal places or n ?

Comment: Yes, probably you can also limit the number of digits of the `mpf` constructors in the `u` part, or get the constructors of constants out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Used Willem Van Onsem's response

```
from mpmath import mp, mpf, nstr


# Bailey Borwein Plouffe algorithm for approximate pi computation
def BBP_pi(n: int, digits: int) -> str:
    assert isinstance(n, int)
    assert isinstance(digits, int)
    
    _pi = mpf(0)
    mp.dps = digits
    for k in range(0,n):
        u = mpf(4)/mpf(8*k+1)-mpf(2)/mpf(8*k+4)-mpf(1)/mpf(8*k+5)-mpf(1)/mpf(8*k+6)
        d = mpf(16.0)**k
        _pi += u/d

    _pi_str = nstr(_pi, 1_000_000)
    
    return _pi_str

def write_to_file(pi_str: str) -> None:
    assert isinstance(pi_str, str)
    
    with open(file='pi.txt', mode='w') as file:
        file.write(pi_str)

def display_pi(pi_str:str, characters_per_row: int) -> None:
    assert isinstance(pi_str, str)
    assert isinstance(characters_per_row, int)
    
    pi_str_size = len(pi_str)
    
    for i,j in zip(range(0, pi_str_size-characters_per_row, characters_per_row), range(characters_per_row, pi_str_size, characters_per_row)):
        print(pi_str[i:j])


digits_precision = 1_000_000
n_iterations = 100_000

approximate_pi = BBP_pi(n=n_iterations, digits=digits_precision)
print(f"Vaule of Pi is : {approximate_pi}")
```